# Counter app doesn't work on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I created 2 buttons and wanna them increase their value clicking on each button.
The code below doesn't work. Please, help ! All this code I render in `html` tag with class `buttons`.

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
  state = { score_1: 0, score_2: 0 };

  updateScore_1() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      score_1: prevState.score_1 += 1
    });
  }
  updateScore_2() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      score_2: prevState.score_2 += 1
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateScore_1.bind(this)}>{this.state.score_1}</button>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.updateScore_2.bind(this)}>{this.state.score_2}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Buttons />,
  document.querySelector('.buttons')
);
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? can you post a complete working snippet?

Answer (score 4):

You missed the keyword return in this.setState. Just add return in `this.setState`:

```
updateScore_2() {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return { score_2: prevState.score_2 + 1 }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write `score_1: prevState.score_1 + 1` instead of `score_1: prevState.score_1 += 1`. In your case you are mutating the state, however using the setState callback you need to return the updated state

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({   // notice the `({` here
  [key]: prevState[key] +1
}));
```

Also you can simply use one handler instead of two

```js
class Buttons extends React.Component {
  state = { score_1: 0, score_2: 0 };

  updateScore(key) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      [key]: prevState[key] +1
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateScore.bind(this, 'score_1')}>{this.state.score_1}</button>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.updateScore.bind(this, 'score_2')}>{this.state.score_2}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Buttons />,
  document.querySelector('.buttons')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue I guess was from the fact that in the setState methods your were not returning the new state which should have been passed to the setState method

```
  updateScore_1() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      score_1: prevState.score_1 + 1
    });
  }
```

A couple of parentheses solves your issue or you can just put a return in from of the new state object. See complete solution below:

```
class Buttons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { score_1: 0, score_2: 0 };
    this.updateScore_1 = this.updateScore_1.bind(this);
    this.updateScore_2 = this.updateScore_2.bind(this);
  }

  updateScore_1() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      score_1: (prevState.score_1 += 1)
    }));
  }
  updateScore_2() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      score_2: (prevState.score_2 += 1)
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateScore_1}>{this.state.score_1}</button>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.updateScore_2}>{this.state.score_2}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Buttons />,
  document.querySelector('.buttons')
);
```